# Dynamic Tree Creation in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring-hibernate Framework and Oracle database. Now there is a table named project. each record has got an unique id,name and a parent_id column. Say the table has got these following records...

```
ID NAME PARENT_ID
1  A     NULL
2  B     1
3  C     NULL
4  D     3
5  E     3
```

now i have create a tree view where these records will be displayed in according to their Parent-Child relationship. Like This..

```
1---P
   ch---2
3---P
   ch--4
   ch--5
```

Now can anyone help me how to create the tree dynamically fetching records from the database dynamically. And what will be the Data Access Object(DAO) and the Implementation of the DAO..

any help or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: I'd just write a little class that contains a `List` of type itself. You can create a tree that way. You can also have a function in the class that can obtain an object based on the id for example. Have it search recursively in the 'children' objects. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

First select only PARENT_ID. Then for select everything where ID is IN the previous array of results (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

- From this you can then create parent in the tree and then lazy load children on expand.
- Or you can populate tree with children immidiately. You just select all where PARENT_ID is NOT NULL and attach them to appropriate parent (by PARENT_ID).

I'm not sure what DAO has to do with it. But in case you just want some abstraction you can use DAO pattern.

DAO could have methods like: *getAllParents, getChildrenForParentId, getAllChildren,* ...

Comment: can you give me an example of constructing the tree and populate the tree with its child-nodes...or any reference...

Comment: I basically told you the algorithm for it. You'll have to figure the rest for your self ...

Answer (score 0):

Just made self table reference in POM (.java class) with List type one to many annotation.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID",nullable=true)
@OrderBy(clause = "NAME")
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_child_project")     
private List<Project> projects= new ArrayList<Project>();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Oracle Hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). Since you are using Oracle DB, you are in luck.

But the only way this can done thru Hibernate is by using a native query and mapping the results back to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions, I'll try to steer you in the right direction -- this might not drop you to your destination.

- Create your `Entities`, See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html)
- You may not need a DAO, just create a business class to query the database. (Hint: use `EntityManager` in case you are using Hibernate's JPA implementation), See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/)
- Then display it as a tree in your browser, assuming you are working on a webapp

**Note:** *You can come again and ask specific questions regarding how, as a separate question.*

**Related thread**

- [How to implement self join in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714328/how-to-implement-self-join-in-jpa)